# How do I set up the lighting to take this portrait?

Tags: portrait, studio-lighting, reverse-engineering, gels

[image]

I don't have much experience with photography. I've been watching a bunch of videos on using gels and led lights. I'm just trying to figure out the best/ cheapest way a rookie can go about getting this shot. Thank you!

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?"
questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and
edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, 
too. Thank you!

Comment: What's in the "bunch of videos" that you're having problems with?

Comment: @Hueco I don't think that title edit really helps. How many different possible portrait lighting setups are there? The title needs to help us tell questions apart in the future.

Comment: @mattdm then edit it, by all means. The previous title was exactly the same as a million other downed and closed questions. At least now it’s perfectly on topic and is even +3. If you would like to see some adjectives in the title, then please add them or suggest them.

Comment: I've edited literally thousands of titles. It's better if the original question asker does it, because they know what they actually want.

Comment: You'll note that this question, despite being on topic, is not attracting answers — as of now, just one, and that one starts off by being rude and condescending. A more descriptive title isn't to make *me* happy. It will help @Samantha actually helpful answers.

Comment: @mattdm I'm all for OP clarifying things but I'm also for helping to salvage good questions before the stackerati kill them. This question doesn't have much in the way of answers because this site doesn't have a heck of a lot of people with studio lighting experience. Personally, I'd like to add a set-up using my blue Yoshi as an example, but I haven't had a chance.

Comment: That's fine. If you want to help and don't think the original poster will, can you please provide a distinctive title?

Answer (score 3):

Samantha: Stop watching a bunch of videos about gels and gear and whatever. Get a victim... I mean, a model, and experiment. If you can not get another person to model, learn how to use a timer on your camera and take self-portraits.

---

What do you see on the image? The light is clearly red, so get any transparent or translucent red thing. A bag, a Coke sticker or some cellophane paper.

**Just take some precautions not starting a fire because the lamp may get hot.**

But the red color is not really important.

You can take a grayscale image and tweak the curves to look similar

[image].

<sub>[Image from here](https://pixabay.com/es/photos/portrait-chica-estudio-femenino-4447229/)</sub>

But most important: Where do you see the light coming from? **The shadows show that it is behind and below.**

So take one lamp and put it behind you, take a picture, move it and take another image.

You probably need another lamp, so get another and put them behind you and keep taking images.

A rough diagram of the location of the lights:

[image]